# CSS borders disappearing on jQuery scroll function

Tags: jquery, css

I've created a fixed table header for an HTML table on my website. When scrolling down, the table header stays at the top like I want it to, so the user can remember what column categories there are. However, the CSS I declared for each `<th>` element goes away when scrolling down, with that CSS being the borders (somehow the font weight and text alignment is retained). Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tableFixHead">
    <table id="Downloads" class="sort">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Application</th>
                <th>Release Version</th>
                <th>Application Type</th>
                <th>Download File Type</th>
                <th>Download File Size</th>
                <th>Download Button</th>
                <th>Download Progress</th>
                <th>Download Message</th>
                <th>Save File</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!--Rows for the body of the table-->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
table {
    margin: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tableFixHead {
   overflow-y: auto;
   height: 600px;
}

.tableFixHead thead th {
    background-color: orange;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #3F2860;
 }
```

**jQuery:**

```
var $th = $('.tableFixHead').find('thead th')
$('.tableFixHead').on('scroll', function() {
   $th.css('transform', 'translateY('+ this.scrollTop +'px)');
});
```

As part of an effort to retain/maintain the borders, I edited the `css()` method in the jQuery, but the same output results:

```
$th.css({'font-weight':'600', 'text-align':'center', 'border':'3px solid #3F2860', 'transform':'translateY('+ this.scrollTop + 'px)'});
```

And from the documentation I've read, the `css()` method doesn't overwrite the previous styling you placed on your elements, but appends to it. So I don't think my issue is with the jQuery. The table is on the page https://maxstechandmathsite.azurewebsites.net/Random about one-third of the way down. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not seeing CSS change on scroll. What is exactly happening in your case? It's just disappearing all together? Doesn't seem to be here. https://jsfiddle.net/x2e70Lw1/

Comment: Why don't you just move those CSS styles on your `<th>` to a stylesheet instead of putting them inline?

Comment: @Keith I apologize, I was wrong about multiple properties disappearing. It's actually just the borders for some reason. I tried your JSFiddle and it worked there, but somehow it won't work on my end, which is on this web page: https://maxstechandmathsite.azurewebsites.net/Random. The table is about one-third down the page.

Comment: @zgood I realized the same thing after posting this question, but having the styles in a .css file or inline makes no difference to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have border-collapse: collapse; on your table element which gets rid of the borders. If you change it and then markup your table with the border style you want, it should work. If you take a closer look, the borders you have added aren't even there ( make it like 13px ). You'll just see a big gap with the actual table scrolling behind it.

```
table{
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.tableFixHead thead th, .tableFixHead td{
  border: 3px solid #3F2860;
}
```

Comment: I see you must have inspected the webpage and then seen the properties of the `table` element. Nice catch!